# IllegalArgumentException: @EnableTransactionManagement is not present on importing class

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, spring-java-config

I'm trying to configure all spring application contexts in my application in generic way.
I have `GeneralDSConfiguration` class which is a general configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class GeneralDSConfiguration implements InitializingBean {

    private String databaseURL;
    private String databaseUserName;
    private String databasePassword;

    public GeneralDSConfiguration(String databaseURL, String databaseUserName, String databasePassword) {
        this.databaseURL = databaseURL;
        this.databaseUserName = databaseUserName;
        this.databasePassword = databasePassword;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Assert.hasText(databaseURL);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        ds.setAccessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed(true);
        ds.setUrl(databaseURL);
        ds.setUsername(databaseUserName);
        ds.setPassword(databasePassword);

        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }
   }
```

Multiple classes like `ConcretteDSConfiguration` is used to build application contexts.

```
@Configuration
public class ConcretteDSConfiguration extends GeneralDSConfiguration {

    public ConcretteDSConfiguration() {
        super("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/database", "postgres", "");
    }
}
```

When I try to load application context with `new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ConcretteDSConfiguration.class)`, the IllegalArgumentException will be thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @EnableTransactionManagement is not present on importing class 'foo.bar.ConcretteDSConfiguration' as expected
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AdviceModeImportSelector.selectImports(AdviceModeImportSelector.java:72)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:328)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:282)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:73)
```

It's definitelly all along of inheritance, because if I put `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation to `ConcretteDSConfiguration` class, everything works fine. But I'm trying to find a **generic** way to write configs, and don't want to put this annotation to every configuration class.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `@EnableTransactionManagement` isn't `@Inherited`.

Anyway it is just enough to place any `@Enable...` annotation only on one your `@Configuration`, so, may you'll review your model and split it to several config classes and use them to build `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.

It isn't clear how you want to achieve good solution with that inheritance, because you end up with an issues, when one bean overrides another, because all your inheritors populates the same beans: `dataSource()`, `transactionManager()` etc...

Try to populate database properties with different `@PropertySource` for each target context and single `GeneralDSConfiguration` with `@EnableTransactionManagement` and those beans.